# Contextily, how to get max zoom allowable and set map extents accordingly

Tags: zooming, geopandas, contextily

Using Python 3.8, GeoPandas, and Contextily, I am plotting a lot of maps in different areas at different zoom levels (looping through list of points in a GeoDataFrame). Different zoom levels work for different global areas.

What is the best way to set the zoom to the max allowable, capturing the points that I am plotting? In the code below, I don't know how to:

1. Return max zoom allowable (I just used 13 in second plot because that was in error message)
2. Change the extents in the second plot-- the extents of the second plot are the same as the first; I would have expected that changing the zoom level would change the extents

I think I have correctly set the EPSG, which was the gist of the answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64755552/contextily-add-basemap-uses-wrong-extent-and-zoom-level).

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import contextily as ctx
from shapely.geometry import Point
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

long, lat = [(-118.02, -118.051, -118.04), (39.499, 39.512, 39.501)]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lat, long)), columns =['lat', 'long'])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['long'], df['lat']))
gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7.5), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])

gdf.plot(ax = ax1)
ctx.add_basemap(ax1, crs='epsg:4326', source=ctx.providers.Esri.WorldShadedRelief)
ax1.tick_params('x', labelrotation=90)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax1.set_title('Auto-Zoom')

gdf.plot(ax = ax2)
ctx.add_basemap(ax2, crs='epsg:4326', source=ctx.providers.Esri.WorldShadedRelief, zoom = 13)
ax2.tick_params('x', labelrotation=90)
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_title('Defined Zoom')
```

[image]

Comment: Add option `reset_extent=False` to `ctx.add_basemap(ax2, ... )` and run again.

Comment: that worked, thanks. do you know how to extract the zoom range in the message box? it's not always "13" it varies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is confirmed by the asker. Adding option `reset_extent=False` to `ctx.add_basemap(ax2, ... )` will solve the problem of plotting on `ax2`.

For checking a possible zoom value before actually using it. Use this

```
# Test if zoom: 28 is valid or not?
retval = ctx.tile._validate_zoom(28, ctx.providers.Esri.WorldShadedRelief, auto=True)
```

The value return, here `retval` represents a valid zoom value (less or equal the check value). In this case, `28` is used to check but `13` is returned. Thus 13 represents the maximum valid zoom for that particular basemap tiles' images.